# how can I get IMEI on IOS with ionic framework

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework

how can I get IMEI on IOS with ionic framework ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use the "Device" object from [Cordova](http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/2.5.0/cordova_device_device.md.html). The device object describes the device's hardware and software. Since "device" is assigned to the window object, it is implicitly in the global scope so you can easily call it in your onDeviceReady function eg:

```
var deviceID = device.uuid;
```

On iOS, no permissions are required.

This will not be possible sadly in **iOS7**, Apple stopped access to these details in iOS7 I believe.

Comment: thank's, I'm newbie in development mobile. there are any number or prefixe number in IOS 7 ?

Comment: Maybe you can store a GUID, Pseudo-Random Number or something generated at install time... (i really mean, the first time you run the app). Valid my answer ;)

Comment: Is device id and IMEI same? I wonder as the question was asked on IMEI