# How to get an IMEI number without restarting an application using ionic-angular?

Tags: javascript, angular

```
getID_UID(type) {
  if(type == "IMEI"){
    return this.uid.IMEI;
  }
}
```

How can I get the `IMEI` number using ionic app using ionic-angular?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Retrieve IMEI number/ sim number/mobile number via mobile browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7413305/retrieve-imei-number-sim-number-mobile-number-via-mobile-browser)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how can I get IMEI on IOS with ionic framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25413697/how-can-i-get-imei-on-ios-with-ionic-framework)